# How do I input into a command prompt, that's ran from a batch file, from a java application

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, command-prompt

I was wondering if there was a way to input into command prompt, that is running from an executed batch file, from a java program. Ex. I have this timer that starts at 9 AM and ends at 9 PM.. I get the batch to start but when i want it to stop i can't get the "stop" to enter into the command prompt to initiate the batch file command. Please help and Thank You!

```
public class Main extends Voids{
String start = "09:00:00 AM";
String end = "09:00:00 PM";
public Main()
{
    try
    {
        int x = 1;
        while(x == 1)
        {
            x = 2;
            if(x == 2)
            {
                SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("hh:mm:ss a");
                Date date = new Date();
                System.out.println(ft.format(date));
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                if(ft.format(date).equals(stime))
                {
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start start.bat");
                    Thread.sleep(43200000);
                    try{
                        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                        Process process = runtime.exec("stop"); // you might need the full path
                        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
                        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                        String line;

                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            System.out.println(line);
                        }
                        }catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            e.getStackTrace();
                        }
                }else
                {
                    x = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION: \n");
        e.getStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Batch:

```
@ECHO off
cls
:start
ECHO Enter "stop" to end session
set /p choice=:
if '%choice%'=='' ECHO "%choice%" is not valid please try again
if '%choice%'=='stop' goto stop
ECHO.
goto start
:stop
ECHO STOPPING SESSION
pause
exit
```

Comment: The real question is why are you using batch at all rather than just doing it in java from System.in

Comment: @Quirliom Because I want to see if this will work for external files not just all around using java. Just messing around with java. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have already an `InputStream`. now obtain an `OutputStream` in an analogous way, and simply write to it.